# How to reduce the space between two words. My JSP looks like this sortby: Date.I want to reduce the space between sortby: Date

Tags: css

how can we reduce the space between the word in UI page.

I have multiple words and all are in the random location.I want to place those words properly

Comment: Please show what you have already attempted and what you are trying to accomplish (code)

Answer (score 0):

using css  , assign `word-spacing: 1px;`or `letter-spacing: 1px;`value is according to your convinience. assign this code to the div or tag you want to reduce the space b/w words

Answer (score 0):

here in your question sortby: date is there simply remove space b/w colon and date or use **`<pre></pre>`** tag in your html code to display the text as u want as if we want to add space browser show only one space but with pre tag we can give as much space as we want **similarly can reduce space**